PHP code issue causing grid container and bootstrap 5 cards (grid-items) not to render on web-page loading?
I am trying to create a grid container that will dynamically display bootstrap cards of treeseed items that I added to MySQL database.The items should be displayed on the shop portion of a webpage I am making for arboretum I can make a connection to the database and get data back but from the moment I included DOMDocument elements within the code I have not got the expected output.
//shopconnect.php
$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
function generateTreeCard(){
  // global $domDoc;
  $topicDiv = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('div'); 
  $topicDiv->setAttribute('class','tree-card'); //tree-card div is to be appended to the container mt-3
  return $topicDiv; //DONE ALREADY AT END OF THE LOOP BELOW
}

function generateCardBody(){
  $cardBody = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('div');
  $cardBody->setAttribute('class','card-body');
  return $cardBody;  //DONE ALREADY APPENDED TO TREECARD BELOW IN THE LOOP
}


function addheaderH4Text($value){
  $cardTitle = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('h4',$value);//needs to be appended on to card body
  $cardTitle->setAttribute('class','card-title');//needs to be appended on to card body
  return $cardTitle; //ALREADY DONE IN THE LOOP BELOW
}

function generateInfoText(){
  $information = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('p','Information:');
  $information->setAttribute('class','info-text:');
  return $information; //DONE ALREADY IN LOOP BELOW VIA INFO PARAGRAPH VARIABLE
}

function generateListElements($key,$value){
  $resultItem = "";
  switch($key){
    case "commonName":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
      break;
    case "speciesName":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
      break;
    case "family":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
      break;
    case "seedcostInclVAT":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
      break;
    case "quantityInStock":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
      break;
    case "seedNumberPerPack":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
      break;
    case "colour":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
      break;
    case "hardiness":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
      break;
    case "soilType":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
      break;
    case "soilAcidity":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
      break;
    case "description":
      $resultItem = $GLOBALS['domDoc']->createElement('li',"$key : $value"); 
    break;
  }
  return $resultItem; //needs to be appended to the productInfoList variable <ul>
}

$outerContainer = $domDoc->createElement('div');
$outerContainer->setAttribute('class','items-wrapper');

$productInfoList = $domDoc->createElement('ul');
$listElementResult = "";

$imgCollectorArr = [];
$h4Text = "";
$cardBody = "";
$treeCard = "";
$treeImage1 = "";
$infoParagraph = "";
$cardContainer = "";

portion of code causing issues (shown below) is the nested foreach loop. I am using the functions above to create the DOM elements necessary to build the bootstrap cards (items) dynamically. 

foreach($treeSeedArr as $key => $value){
   $infoParagraph = generateInfoText(); //Just to display "Information:"
  foreach($value as $key1 => $value1){
     echo $key1 . " has a value of " . $value1 . "<br/>";
     if($key1 === 'commonName'){
      $h4Text = addheaderH4Text($value1); //GENERATE h4 text line'
      $cardBody = generateCardBody()->appendChild($h4Text)->appendChild($infoParagraph);
     }
     if($key1 !== 'id' && $key1 !== 'treeImage1' && $key1 !== 'treeImage2' && $key1 !== 'treeImage3'){
       $listElementResult = generateListElements($key1,$value1); // the bullet pointed list of properties
       $productInfoList->appendChild($listElementResult);//this is the <ul> tag
     }
     if($key1 === 'treeImage1' && !(is_null($value["treeImage1"]))){

        if(array_key_exists("treeImage2",$value) && !(is_null($value["treeImage2"]))){
          $imgCollectorArr["treeImage1"] = $value[$key1];
          continue; //if a treeseed has more at least 2 images 
        }
        $treeImage1 = generatetreeImage1($value1); //this is if a treeseed only has one image
        $treeCard = generateTreeCard()->appendChild($treeImage1)->appendChild($cardBody);
     }

     if($key1 === 'treeImage2' && !(is_null($value["treeImage2"]))){
        if(array_key_exists("treeImage3",$value) && !(is_null($value["treeImage3"]))){
          $imgCollectorArr["treeImage2"] = $value[$key1];
          continue; //if a treeseed has 3 images instead of 2
        }
         //design what happens when there are 2 images
         $slideBox1 = $domDoc->createElement('div');
         $slideBox1->setAttribute('class','mySlides fade');
         $countText1 = $domDoc->createElement('div','1 / 2');
         $countText1->setAttribute('class','numbertext');
         $slideBox1->appendChild($countText1);
         $firstImg = $domDoc->createElement('img');
         $firstImg->setAttribute('style','width:100%');
         $firstImg->setAttribute('src',$imgCollectorArr["treeImage1"]);
         $slideBox1->appendChild($firstImg);

         $slideBox2 = $domDoc->createElement('div');
         $slideBox2->setAttribute('class','mySlides fade');
         $countText2 = $domDoc->createElement('div','2 / 2');
         $countText2->setAttribute('class','numbertext');
         $slideBox2->appendChild($countText2);
         $secondImg = $domDoc->createElement('img');
         $secondImg->setAttribute('style','width:100%');
         $secondImg->setAttribute('src',"$value1");
         $slideBox2->appendChild($secondImg);
        
          $treeCard->appendChild($slideBox1);
          $treeCard->appendChild($slideBox2);

        //attach on to treecard
        $previousLink = $domDoc->createElement('a','&#10094;');
        $previousLink->setAttribute('class','prev');
        $previousLInk->setAttribute('onclick','plusSlides(-1)');

        $forwardLink = $domDoc->createElement('a','&#10095;');
        $forwardLink->setAttribute('class','next');
        $forwardLInk->setAttribute('onclick','plusSlides(1)');
        $treeCard->appendChild($previousLink);
        $treeCard->appendChild($forwardLink);


          //dots/circles
      $dotCircleBox1 = $domDoc->createElement('div');
      $dotCircleBox1->setAttribute('style','text-align:center');
      $dotSpanA = $domDoc->createElement('span');
      $dotSpanA->setAttribute('class','dot');
      $dotSpanA->setAttribute('onclick','currentSlide(1)');


      $dotSpanB = $domDoc->createElement('span');
      $dotSpanB->setAttribute('class','dot');
      $dotSpanB->setAttribute('onclick','currentSlide(2)');

      $dotCircleBox1->appendChild($dotSpanA);
      $dotCircleBox1->appendChild($dotSpanB);
      $treeCard->appendChild($dotCircleBox1);
     }

     if($key1 === 'treeImage3' && !(is_null($value[$key1]))){
      $slideBoxA = $domDoc->createElement('div');
      $slideBoxA->setAttribute('class','mySlides fade');
      $countTextA = $domDoc->createElement('div','1 / 3');
      $countTextA->setAttribute('class','numbertext');
      $slideBox1->appendChild($countTextA);
      $firstImg = $domDoc->createElement('img');
      $firstImg->setAttribute('style','width:100%');
      $firstImg->setAttribute('src',$imgCollectorArr["treeImage1"]);
      $slideBoxA->appendChild($firstImg);

      $slideBoxB = $domDoc->createElement('div');
      $slideBoxB->setAttribute('class','mySlides fade');
      $countTextB = $domDoc->createElement('div','2 / 3');
      $countTextB->setAttribute('class','numbertext');
      $slideBoxB->appendChild($countTextB);
      $secondImg = $domDoc->createElement('img');
      $secondImg->setAttribute('style','width:100%');
      $secondImg->setAttribute('src',$imgCollectorArr["treeImage2"]);
      $slideBoxB->appendChild($secondImg);

      $slideBoxC = $domDoc->createElement('div');
      $slideBoxC->setAttribute('class','mySlides fade');
      $countTextC = $domDoc->createElement('div','3 / 3');
      $countTextC->setAttribute('class','numbertext');
      $slideBoxC->appendChild($countTextB);
      $thirdImg = $domDoc->createElement('img');
      $thirdImg->setAttribute('style','width:100%');
      $thirdImg->setAttribute('src',$value1);
      $slideBoxC->appendChild($thirdImg);

      $treeCard->appendChild($slideBoxA);
      $treeCard->appendChild($slideBoxB);
      $treeCard->appendChild($slideBoxC);


      $previousLink = $domDoc->createElement('a','&#10094;');
      $previousLink->setAttribute('class','prev');
      $previousLInk->setAttribute('onclick','plusSlides(-1)');

      $forwardLink = $domDoc->createElement('a','&#10095;');
      $forwardLink->setAttribute('class','next');
      $forwardLInk->setAttribute('onclick','plusSlides(1)');

      $treeCard->appendChild($previousLink);
      $treeCard->appendChild($forwardLink);

      //dots/circles
      $dotCircleBox2 = $domDoc->createElement('div');
      $dotCircleBox2->setAttribute('style','text-align:center');
      $dotSpan1 = $domDoc->createElement('span');
      $dotSpan1->setAttribute('class','dot');
      $dotSpan1->setAttribute('onclick','currentSlide(1)');


      $dotSpan2 = $domDoc->createElement('span');
      $dotSpan2->setAttribute('class','dot');
      $dotSpan2->setAttribute('onclick','currentSlide(2)');


      $dotSpan3 = $domDoc->createElement('span');
      $dotSpan3->setAttribute('class','dot');
      $dotSpan3->setAttribute('onclick','currentSlide(3)');

      $dotCircleBox2->appendChild($dotSpan1);
      $dotCircleBox2->appendChild($dotSpan2);
      $dotCircleBox2->appendChild($dotSpan3); 
      $treeCard->appendChild($dotCircleBox2);

      
     }
  }
    $cardBody->appendChild($productInfoList);
    $treeCard->appendChild($cardBody);
  //for the forward and backwards arrow heads
    $cardContainer = $domDoc->createElement('div');//needs to be appended to items-wrapper
    if(!(is_null($value["treeImage2"])) || !(is_null($value["treeImage3"]))){
      $cardContainer->setAttribute('class','container mt-3 slides-container'); 
    }else{
      $cardContainer->setAttribute('class','container mt-3'); 
    }
    
    $cardContainer->appendChild($treeCard);
  
  $outerContainer->appendChild($cardContainer);
}
$domDoc->appendChild($outerContainer);
$htmlString = $domDoc->saveHTML();
echo $htmlString;


//gardenshop.php (I require once shopconnect.php)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="author" content="Jacob">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./gardenshop.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="../tree_icon.png">
      <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script src="./slidelogic.js"></script> -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" 
      integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A==" 
      crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    </head>
    <body>
       <header>
         <div class="img-container"></div>
         <section class="shop-header"><h1>SPROUTY'S GARDENING SHOP</h1></section>
         <ul class="header-grp">
           <li class="header-item"><a id="back-link" href="./homepage.html"><i id="header-arrow" class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left-long"></i>Back To Homepage</a></li>
           <li class="header-item"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></li>
         </ul>
       </header>
       <main>
          <div class="f-container">
            <div class="box-1">
              <dl>
                <dt class="inline-dt">Contains Stainless Steel</dt>:&nbsp<input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" id="tool_stainlessstl" name="tool_stainlessstl"/>
                <dt class="inline-dt">FSC &#40;Forest Stewardship Council&#41; certified</dt>:&nbsp<input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" id="tool_fsc_cert" name="tool_fsc_cert"/>
                <dt class="inline-dt">In Stock</dt>:&nbsp<input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" id="tool_stock" name="tool_stock"/>
              </dl>
             </div>
             <div class="box-2">
               <dl>
                <dt class="inline-dt">In Stock</dt>:&nbsp<input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" id="giftcard_stock" name="giftcard_stock"/>
                <dt class="inline-dt">Weight &#40;grams&#41;</dt>:&nbsp<input type="range" min="0" max="50" id="giftcard_weight" name="giftcard_weight"/>
                <dt class="inline-dt">Price</dt>:&nbsp<input type="range" min="0" max="30" step="0.01" id="giftcard_price" name="giftcard_price"/>  
                <dt class="inline-dt">FSC &#40;Forest Stewardship Council&#41; certified</dt>:&nbsp<input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" id="giftcard_fsc_cert" name="giftcard_fsc_cert"/>
               </dl>
             </div>
             <div class="box-3">
              <dl>
                <dt class="inline-dt">In Stock</dt>:&nbsp<input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" id="fertiliser_stock" name="fertiliser_stock"/>
                <dt class="inline-dt">Litres &#40;Capacity&#41;</dt>:&nbsp<input type="range" min="10" max="60" id="fertiliser_capacity" name="fertiliser_capacity"/>
                <dt class="inline-dt">Price</dt>:&nbsp<input type="range" min="0" max="20" step="0.01" id="fertiliser_price" name="fertiliser_price"/>
              </dl>
             </div>
             <div class="box-4">
              <dl>
                <dt class="inline-dt">In Stock</dt>:&nbsp<input type="checkbox" id="treeseed_stock" name="treeseed_stock"/>
                <dt class="inline-dt">Soil Type</dt>:&nbsp<select name="soiltypes" id="soiltypes">
                  <option value="chalk">chalk</option>
                  <option value="sand">sand</option>
                  <option value="loam">loam</option>
                  <option value="clay">clay</option>
                </select>
                <dt class="inline-dt">Soil Acidity</dt>:&nbsp<select name="soilacidity" id="soilacidity">
                  <option value="acid">acid</option>
                  <option value="alkaline">alkaline</option>
                  <option value="neutral">neutral</option>
                </select>
                <dt class="inline-dt">Hardiness</dt>:&nbsp<select name="hardiness" id="hardiness">
                  <option value="hardy">hardy</option>
                  <option value="tender">tender</option>
                  <option value="hardy/half-hardy">hardy/half-hardy</option>
                </select>
                <dt class="inline-dt">Price</dt>:&nbsp<input type="range" min="0" max="4" step="0.01" id="treeseed_price" name="treeseed_price"/>

              </dl>
             </div>
             <div class="box-5">
              <dl>
                 <dt class="inline-dt">In Stock</dt>:&nbsp<input type="checkbox" id="compost_stock" name="compost_stock"/>
                 <dt class="inline-dt">Is Biodegradable</dt>:&nbsp<input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" id="compost_degradable" name="compost_degradable"/>
                 <dt class="inline-dt">Litres &#40;Capacity&#41;</dt>:&nbsp<span><input type="range" min="0" max="280" id="compost_capacity" name="compost_capacity"/>
                 <dt class="inline-dt">Price</dt>:&nbsp<input type="range" min="0" max="20" step="0.01" id="compost_price" name="compost_price"/>
              </dl>
            </div>
          </div>
            <?php require_once './shopconnect.php'; ?>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./slidelogic.js"></script>

       </main>

    </body>
</html>

I added conditional if statements inside the nested foreach loops to create bootstrap cards that could hold a standalone treeimage or more than one treeimage in which case each card would have a slideshow.
Unfortunately the output is the following and the console in my Chrome browser shows no errors:


What is the expected output?

@mykaf a grid container with grid items where the grid items are bootstrap 5 cards with images of trees/treeseeds and text on them. Go to here to see what I mean: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_cards.php

Intresting! you are generating html from php, very rarely I see someone do that. Truth is it very unlikely anyone would be able to help you with problems in your markup by just looking at your php code. I would advise you to analyse the generated html by using "view-source"

True...start by building the html you want by hand, as a static page. Then once you've got that right and you're happy with how the page looks, you can write php code to autogenerate it. Use your browser's  Developer Tools to see what the php code is outputting into the page when you're testing, and compare it to your static demo to find any mistakes

@Vinay Okay will try that, thanks

@ADyson Thanks for replying, I will try statically making the cards then try generate them dynamically.

You also might inspect the html that it's currently generating and see if the expected image tags exist, then check their src attributes to ensure they are correct.
